# Undefined Index in Checkbox

Tags: php, mysql

```
<form method="POST" action="<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
    <table border="1" cellpadding="4">
        <tr>
            <th>Id</th>
            <th>Name</th>

        </tr>
        <?php
        include('connect.php');
        $getQuery = "SELECT id,username,admin FROM tutorial_users ORDER BY id ASC";
        $getResult = mysql_query($getQuery) or die("Query not executed");
        while (list($id, $userName, $admin) = mysql_fetch_row($getResult)) {
            ?>
            <?php
            $checked = ($admin == 1) ? 'checked="checked"' : '';
            ?>
            <tr align="center">
                <td><?php echo $id; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $userName; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo "<input type='checkbox' name='admin[]' value='$id' $checked>"; ?></td>
            <?php } ?>
        <tr>
    </table>
    <p>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Update Role">
    </p>
</form>
<?php
$updated = FALSE;
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $admin = $_POST['admin'];
    $admin = join(",", $admin);
    $admin = "(" . $admin . ")";
    $defaultQuery = "UPDATE tutorial_users SET admin=0";
    $defaultResult = mysql_query($defaultQuery);
    $upQuery = "UPDATE tutorial_users SET admin=1 WHERE id IN $admin";
    echo $upQuery;
    $upResult = mysql_query($upQuery);
    $updated = TRUE;
}
?>
```

In the above code I have 2 questions:

1. Lets say I want every check box to be unchecked and then when I press the submit, it gives me `undefined index $admin`, how can I fix this?

   It is working fine when I'm checking at least one box and it passes the value to the POST array.
2. Secondly I would like to know that is this a good approach to achieve result or we can have some other way? Personally I'm feeling it bad because if I have 1000 record then it will take a lot of time to update 2 queries one by one.

Result: What I want is pretty simple that the checked box should have value = 1 where as unchecked have 0.

Comment: I am rather confused by your update query, first you set all entries to admin 0 then you set a specific admin to 1 why not just update the ones changed with a single query?

Comment: **don't** use mysql_* functions, they are deprecated, use mysqli or PDO instead. Also be sure to escape all request parameters before inserting them in a query (or just use prepared statements)

Comment: for `$admin` you can added it to the `if` such as `if(isset($_POST['admin'], $_POST['submit'])){`

Comment: @Prix It is because what if i want to remove admin role from a user ? and update some users to admin. In ur case it will update the new checked box but the old one will remained value=1

Comment: @RameezShah that's called poor design, a better way would be to give it an action and by the action you ask the user to select the records that they want changed so you know what action it is and what records to change. That's exactly why many systems ask you what you which to do before they do it. For example, have a drop down with the options remove admin, add admin, and a list of id's to check a box from.

Comment: @Prix Great ! I would try this ....Actually i wanted to learn handling checkbox in PHP...Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Checkboxes are not included in the POST data when the form is submitted. You need to call `isset($_POST['admin'])` before you try to do anything else with it.

Also, on a side note, you need to look at the non-deprecated mysqli functions or PDO. The mysql_* functions have been deprecated and will be removed.

Answer (score 0):

Checkboxes only pass value with the form when they are checked, if your form was submitted with no checkbox checked then it will result in `$_POST['admin']` not being associated. You will need to test for the existence of such key by using `isset($_POST['admin']);`.

Comment: How can i set the default value to 0 ? of unchecked box?

Answer (score 0):

You can try my way in your option

```
 <option value="the_value_of_option" <?php if(isset($_POST['something']) && ($_POST['something'] == 'the_value_of_option')){echo "selected";}?> >Label of option</option>
```

happy coding